# Swift: Update UIViewController insets via extension

Tags: swift, overriding, extension-methods, viewcontroller

I wanted to update the UIEdgeInsets of all my view controllers on certain devices and I wanted to see if there's a way to do it globally as an extension, rather than creating a method and calling it in viewDidLoad for each of them. Is there a way to achieve this? I tried using awakeFromNib but this doesn't work.

```
extension UIViewController {

    open override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.additionalSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 100, left: 100, bottom: 100, right: 100)
    }

}
```

I also tried calling self.viewLayoutMarginsDidChange() after changing the edge insets, with no results.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. Am I just overriding the wrong method or is this just not possible, or as easy as I'm thinking.

Comment: Are you using storyboards or frames coding?

Comment: @Ladd.c I am using storyboards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
extension UIViewController {

    open override func awakeAfter(using: NSCoder) -> Any? {
        self.additionalSafeAreaInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 100, left: 100, bottom: 100, right: 100)
        return super.awakeAfter(using: using)
    }

}
```